# Aligning equations by row and column -- with vertical lines

Tags: tables, equations, amsmath

I want to include two sets of equations side-by-side in a table. Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\eqnbox}[2]{
  \begin{minipage}[c]{#1\linewidth}\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
        #2
      \end{aligned}\end{equation*}\end{minipage}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
first set & second set\\
\hline
\eqnbox{.3}{
  x &= \frac{1}{2}\\
  y &= \frac{1}{3}\\
  z &= 3
} &
\eqnbox{.3}{
  x &= 2\\
  y &= 3\\
  z &= 3
}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have tried

1. aligning the rows but putting each equation in `$$`, but then I cannot align vertically by the `=` sign.
2. laying out the entire table using `align`, but then cannot put a vertical line down the middle.
3. adjusting the height of the box by using the height argument to `minipage`, e.g. `\begin{minipage}[c][30pt]{#1\linewidth}`, or enclosing the `minipage` environment within `raisebox`, e.g., `\raisebox{0pt}[30pt][30pt]{}`.

No luck so far -- any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array instead of the tabular and put the *single* equations side by side, not the blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\def\MCA#1{\multicolumn{2}{c!{\quad\vline\quad}}{\text{#1}}}
\def\MCB#1{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\def\arraystretch{1.8}\arraycolsep=1.4pt
$\begin{array}{rl!{\quad\vline\quad}rl}
\MCA{first set} & \MCB{second set}\\\hline
  x &= \frac{1}{2} &   x &= 2\\
  y &= \frac{1}{3} &   y &= 3\\
  z &= 3           &   z &= 3
\end{array}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I like this for the position arguments permitted by `array` and the `vline` specifications which I did not know about -- very awesome.